# Migration with Phalcon and foreign key with schema name?

Tags: php, database-migration, phalcon

When I use phalcon developer tool for generating migration class and table have foreign key

Phalcon delveloper tool is generated migrations with using database name in migration's classes.

```
new Reference('fk_orders_customes1', array(
    'referencedSchema'=>'database_dev',
    'referencedTable'=>'customers',
    'columns'=> array('customers_id'),
    'referencedColumns'=> array('id')
));
```

How to avoid this way? Because Production DB have another name.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. Added an option to handle this correctly to the dev tools and created a pull request.

For a quick solution you can edit the phalcon tools yourself. Just open 'scripts/Phalcon/Mvc/Model/Migration.php' and replace every occurrence of `$tableReference->getSchemaName()` with `$defaultSchema`. This will use the value of the database in your config (Field `dbname`).